# On the "Peano phenomenon" in higher dimensions

Tags: differential-equations, existence-theorems

The following result in one-dimensional differential equations is sometimes referred to as "Peano phenomenon" (see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242302/the-peano-phenomenon-for-differential-equations)).

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, the differential equation
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}=f(x)
\end{align*}
with initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ can only have more than one solution if $f(x_0)=0$.
Is there an analogue of this result in higher dimensions?
If there isn't, what is an example of a differential equation with continuous right hand side with multiple solutions starting from a point $x_0$ such that all components of $f(x_0)$ are non-zero?

Comment: $x'=1, y'=|y|^{1/2}$, $(x,y)(0)=(0,0)$ has non-unique solutions, but the system has no equilibrium points.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to avoid cases like this. I am interested in initial conditions where all components are non-zero.

Comment: If you change coordinates on Christian Remling's example with a 45-degree rotation, I believe you'll get non-uniqueness at the origin with both components of the derivative nonzero.